# How to catch a specific window that could pop-up in any moment

Tags: python, python-3.6, pywinauto

In the app I'm trying to automate there is an error window that could pop-up in literally any moment of application work. Then I need to perform some actions like logging this event and stop next automation steps. So I need to catch this moment. How can I do it?

This window always has the same properties (`auto_id`) so I can describe it before it exist. I can think of using something like a timer which will always check for existence of this window (with the help of `.exists()`, I guess). But maybe there is a better way of doing it?

Comment: You think in the right direction (`.exists()` should work for you). Alternative way might use UIAutomation events subscription (like WindowOpenEvent). But there is no nice wrapper for that. We're experimenting to make automatic "record-replay" script generator in the fork so far. This prototype uses UIAutomation event handlers, and there are no more code with them.

Comment: This is [the prototype](https://github.com/cetygamer/pywinauto/tree/dev-script-generator/pywinauto/script_generator) that can just log most of the events. If you have any ideas how to use these handlers for other tasks, you're welcome to open new issues on GitHub.